# MoreLikeThis in Azure Search

Tags: azure

I'm currently evaluating the new Azure Search feature in Windows Azure. I'm wondering if there's a way to do a [MoreLikeThis](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-more-like-this.html) query similar to lucene/elasticsearch?—pass in a document text and get a list of documents that are similar to the passed in document. I know Azure Search uses elasticsearch in the background ([Source](http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-nosql-database-and-full-text-search-service-previews-available-on-azure-7000032836/)).

I haven't found this anywhere in the API, but maybe I'm missing something hidden in the parameters. I think this is a very useful feature and it would be shame if it's not included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it comes in the new version of azure search : 2015-02-28-Preview
see here : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-api-2015-02-28-preview/

```
moreLikeThis=[key]
```

Comment: Cool. Nice to see they're making some improvements. My scenario is for passing in a document text not currently in the index though (in order to see if what's about to be entered is a duplicate). I'm not going to use Azure Search for now because I need a lot of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample:

```
GET /indexes/[index name]/docs/suggest?[query parameters] 
Host: [search service url] 
accept: application/json 
api-key: [admin key]
```

C#

```
Uri uri = new Uri(_serviceUri, "/indexes/catalog/docs/suggest?$filter=discontinuedDate eq null&$select=productNumber&search=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(searchText));
```

There's a sample project on Codeplex:

https://azuresearchadventureworksdemo.codeplex.com/

Suggestions (Azure Search API):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798936.aspx

(Azure Search API)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798927.aspx

Comment: I thought it might be the Suggest API as well, but it doesn't look like the same functionality. The search field is limited to 25 characters and so in most cases it's impossible to do something like MoreLikeThis. MoreLikeThis is useful for displaying something like "related articles" or for finding potential duplicates in an index.

Comment: MoreLikeThis is different to the Suggest API.  The suggest API is used for things like autocompletion of free text fields, whereas MoreLikeThis is used to return conceptually related documents.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature is not currently available in Azure Search.

See Pablo's comment on [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/azure-new-documentdb-nosql-service-new-search-service-new-sql-alwayson-vm-template-and-more#comment-38509).

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an antique question, but it's one of the first when googling for 'morelikethis azure search'.

Anyway, with the new API version `2019-05-06-Preview` there is a new preview feature called `moreLikeThis` (not in the SDK yet) where you can pass in an `id` of an existing document (I know, not a text like the David asked for). E.g.

```
GET /indexes/[index]/docs?moreLikeThis=[documentId]&api-version=2019-05-06-Preview
```

You can filter the compared fields by defining a list of properties with the `searchFields` parameter, e.g.

```
GET /indexes/[index]/docs?moreLikeThis=[documentId]&searchFields=[field]&api-version=2019-05-06-Preview
```

Of course this can also be POSTed, for more details have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-more-like-this).